# Xna Events Ignore left click followed immediately by double click

Tags: c#, xna, mouseevent

I have a method that dispatches mouse events to a list of listeners.  The problem is that if I just use

```
    [Obsolete]
    private void DispatchOld(MouseEvent e)
    {
        foreach (var listener in _listeners)
        {
            listener.OnMouse(e, _currentState);
        }
    }
```

Then when I double click my mouse, a left click is fired immediately followed by a double click.  I am trying to make it so that if I double click, that is the only 
event that fires, no left click.  So essentially if a left click is detected, i want to hold off on dispatching that event until I know if a double click is next, otherwise
just process events such as middle click, right click and so on, normally without any delays or modification.  With my new code, this almost works except that when I just single left
click, that event does not fire, instead it waits and fires a double click.  Can someone suggest a way to approach this problem, I want to detect single left clicks and double clicks but
not detect a left followed immediately by a double.  So a LRLRLDLLLD should be LRLRDLLD.  Events is a `Stack<MouseEvent>`.  Dispatch is being called within a Update loop after a event is added.

```
    private void Dispatch()
    {
        bool wait = false;

        foreach (var item in Events)
        {
            if (!wait)
            {
                if (item == MouseEvent.LeftClick) { wait = true; } // Delay the left click
                else
                {
                    foreach (var listener in _listeners)
                    {
                        listener.OnMouse(item, _currentState);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (item == MouseEvent.DoubleClick)
                {
                    foreach (var listener in _listeners)
                    {
                        listener.OnMouse(MouseEvent.DoubleClick, _currentState);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var listener in _listeners)
                    {
                        listener.OnMouse(MouseEvent.LeftClick, _currentState); // The delayed event
                        listener.OnMouse(item, _currentState);
                    }
                }

                wait = false; // Delt with wait, continue as normal
            }             
        }

        Events.Clear();
    }
```

I cannot figure out a way of solving this problem and my code feels messy and repetitive,  I could rename and use dispatchOld to get rid of some duplication but I wanted to have everything in one method.  The stream of events are being fired by another part of my program that works fine, detects events and sends them.

---

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
ANSWERED
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

EDIT: I seem to have solved the problem using a `System.Diagnostics.StopWatch()`.

Using a Stopwatch included in System.Diagnostics I was able to get the desired behaviour

```
    private Stopwatch _delayTimer = new Stopwatch();

    private void Dispatch(MouseEvent e)
    {
        foreach (var listener in _listeners)
        {
            listener.OnMouse(e, _currentState);
        }
    }

    private void Dispatcher()
    {
        const long maxDelay = 200;

        foreach (var item in Events)
        {
            if (_delayTimer.IsRunning) // Running because Left trigger
            {
                if (item == MouseEvent.DoubleClick)
                {
                    _delayTimer.Reset();
                    Dispatch(MouseEvent.DoubleClick);
                    return; // Delt with
                }

                if (_delayTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds >= maxDelay) // Waited too long, must be a real left click
                {
                    _delayTimer.Reset();
                    Dispatch(MouseEvent.LeftClick);
                    Dispatch(item);
                    return; // Delt with
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (item == MouseEvent.LeftClick) // Ignore and return, but start timer from zero
                {
                    _delayTimer.Restart();
                    return;
                }
                Dispatch(item);
            }
        }           
    }
```

It is still sort of messy, I renamed Dispatch to Dispatcher and renamed DispatchOld Dispatch.  So as to avoid repeating myself in the Dispatcher method.  I also have come to realize I probably don't need to use a Stack as every time a event is detected in my Update code, the Dispatcher is called, thus there would never be an accumulated stack.  I am in the process of optimizing the code.  For now the above works as advertised and I have once again asked a question and answered it myself.

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer to your question. There is a button below your question that says `Post Your Answer` for that.

Comment: You can also use this answer's code to make a more reliable click detection http://stackoverflow.com/a/16111949/1306322