# How to subscribe to double clicks?

Tags: c#, xna, double-click

I'm trying to find a way to subscribe to double-click event in XNA, and googling gets me winforms related stuff, which isn't the case, I can't use that.

Using `Timespan` and guessing how long the timeout for double click is on a PC is not very reliable.

Default XNA input system also has this little flaw: sometimes a key press or a mouse click gets lost between updates and it would ruin double-click reliability in high load moments of the game.

How do I subscribe to double-click events in .net?

---

The "without using `Control` class events" was removed, since there actually is a way to use that class (see my answer).

Comment: You can create your own input class and handle is there http://www.niedermann.dk/2010/05/12/ClickAndDoubleClickInXNAGames.aspx

Comment: The linked method assumes using preset default interval, I myself prefer quite a bit smaller time interval between clicks, but some people might enjoy greater intervals, and it would mean the wrong double-click timing for them, which could be very inconvenient, so I'd like the "real" double click.

Comment: You can have an option that lets the user change the setting. To get the double click of the system, you can use [SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.doubleclicktime.aspx) (reference Windows.Forms assembly). If you don't want to reference the Windows.Forms assembly, you can use P/Invoke (GetDoubleClickTime() method in User32.dll which gets back the milliseconds the user has set on their machine)

Comment: I see. But isn't there a way to just subscribe to game window's double click event?

Comment: Not AFAIK, but I've found an easier method that may work  (check my answer) for you and works with the user's default double click time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just came up with this:

```
using wf = System.Windows.Forms;

wf.Form form = (wf.Form)wf.Control.FromHandle(this.Window.Handle);
form.MouseDoubleClick += new wf.MouseEventHandler(form_MouseDoubleClick);
```

So there really is a way to do this in XNA using `Control` class :)

Comment: I believe winforms do not work on Xbox so if you are planning on releasing your game on xbox then you should make your own. It's very easy, just look if there is another click in a certain time frame from each click.

Comment: I'm not sure there is even mouse support in Xbox or a double click.

Comment: If you are going to use win forms library your game will not load. If you just use the xna input library to use the mouse it will load fine.

Comment: Anyway, this application is an image viewer, so it's PC only.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own double-click checker as described in [this post](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/51389/310663.aspx).

```
double ClickTimer;
const double TimerDelay = 500;

public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
     ClickTimer += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
     if(Mouse.GetState().LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
     {
          if(ClickTimer < TimerDelay)
              //this is a double click
          else
              //this is a normal click

          ClickTimer = 0;
     }
}
```

In that code, `500` is set as the maximum time in milliseconds a user has to double click.  To get the milliseconds the user has set as their system's maximum double click time (instead of just setting it to an arbitrary value of `500`), you can either import the `Windows.Forms` assembly and read the [SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.doubleclicktime.aspx) property or, if you don't want to import the assembly, you can P/Invoke the `GetDoubleClickTime` method.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern int GetDoubleClickTime();
```

So adding the above method to the XNA code, you can get the user's default double click time like this

```
const double TimerDelay = (double)GetDoubleClickTime();
```